# Android SAX parser

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to implement a robust RSS/Atom reader for android, and since Xerces won't compile I am struggling to find an alternative. I am using org.xmlpull.v1.sax2.Driver(), however this just wraps a DOM parser with SAX callbacks.

Is there anything comparable to Xerces on Android?

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the built in parser `org.xml.sax`

http://www.anddev.org/parsing_xml_from_the_net_-_using_the_saxparser-t353.html

Comment: I am using an rss parser that relies on xerxces (and those callbacks)

Comment: What specifically do you need? Perhaps if you tell us your specific problem or what exactly you need that `org.xml.sax` doesn't do we could help you more.

Comment: org.xml.sax is just the API, not implementation -- you can not use that, there must be an implementation of the API. From what I have read, looks like they wrap a minimal XmlPull impl within SAX API; and that would be lacking much of XML  functionality.

Comment: @Stax: what are you talking about? What does org.xml.sax not have that makes it not functional?

Comment: org.xml.sax is the API, not implementation. There is something that implements all those interfaces; (API) interfaces themselves do nothing. So actual parser classes are not within that package but somewhere else.

But if you meant to just use that default implementation, I think original poster is trying to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

other options are:

Android Sax Parser
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/sax/package-summary.html

[Java handling XML using SAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844458/java-handling-xml-using-sax)

or use the [Simple annotation based XML library](http://simple.sourceforge.net/)