# Java handling XML using SAX

Tags: java, android, xml, sax

I've got XML I need to parse with the given structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<root>
  <tag label="idAd">
    <child label="text">Text</child>
  </tag>
  <tag label="idNumPage">
    <child label1="text" label2="text">Text</child>
  </tag>
</root>
```

I use SAX parser to parse it:

```
RootElement root=new RootElement("root");
android.sax.Element page_info=root.getChild("tag").getChild("child");
page_info.setStartElementListener(new StartElementListener() {

            @Override
            public void start(Attributes attributes) {
                /*---------------*/
            }
        });
```

I want to read second "tag" element attributes(`label1` and `label2`), but my StartElementListener reads first tag, because they have the same structure and attributes(those `label="idAd"` and `label="idNumPage"`) distinguish them. How do I tell StartElementListener to process only second `<tag>` element?

Comment: Just to be clear: what you are using is not SAX, it is some android-specific classes layered on top of SAX. I just mention this because anyone who knows SAX and doesn't know android (like me) is going to be confused by your question.

Comment: I would say that you have started on the wrong foot, if you are working with XML on Android then you really should be using Simple XML (http://simple.sourceforge.net/). I have a blog post that explains how to incorporate into your projects: http://massaioli.homelinux.com/wordpress/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are stuck with the `StartElementListener`-way, you should set a listener to the `tag` element, and when it's `label` equals "idNumPage" set a flag, so the other `StartElementListener` you've set on the `child` element should be read.

**Update**
Below is a sample of how to do this using these listeners:

```
android.sax.Element tag = root.getChild("tag");
final StartTagElementListener listener = new StartTagElementListener();
tag.setStartElementListener(listener);

android.sax.Element page_info = tag.getChild("child");
page_info.setStartElementListener(new StartElementListener()
{
    @Override
    public void start(Attributes attributes)
    {
        if (listener.readNow())
        {
            //TODO: you are in the tag with label="idNumPage"
        }
    }
});
```

And the `StartTagElementListener` is implemented with an extra `readNow` getter, to let us know when to read the `child` tag's attributes:

```
public final class StartTagElementListener implements StartElementListener
{
    private boolean doReadNow = false;

    @Override
    public void start(Attributes attributes)
    {
        doReadNow = attributes.getValue("label").equals("idNumPage");
    }

    public boolean readNow()
    {
        return doReadNow;
    }
}
```

**PS**: Did you consider using a `org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler` implementation for this task?

Comment: Now I use anonymous inner classes as listeners for each tag, I think that it's not effective, so I considered using DefaultHandler.

Comment: There's no problem with (anonymous)inner classes, but in this case a `DefaultHandler` implementation was the better choice, I'm glad you made it!